# How do inheritedSolverBenchmark and solverBenchmark merge?

Tags: optaplanner

I want to experiment with different local search configurations. They all use the same neighborhood, so I defined the unionMoveSelector in the inheritedSolverBenchmark.

```
<inheritedSolverBenchmark>
    <solver>
        ...
        <localSearch>
            <termination>
                <unimprovedSecondsSpentLimit>30</unimprovedSecondsSpentLimit>
            </termination>
            <unionMoveSelector>
                <changeMoveSelector />
                <swapMoveSelector />
                <pillarChangeMoveSelector>
                    <subPillarType>ALL</subPillarType>
                </pillarChangeMoveSelector>
                <pillarSwapMoveSelector>
                    <subPillarType>ALL</subPillarType>
                </pillarSwapMoveSelector>
            </unionMoveSelector>
        </localSearch>
    </solver>
</inheritedSolverBenchmark>
```

Then I created various benchmarks to compare:

```
<solverBenchmark>
    <name>Tabu</name>
    <solver>
        <localSearch>
            <localSearchType>TABU_SEARCH</localSearchType>
        </localSearch>
    </solver>
</solverBenchmark>
<solverBenchmark>
    <name>LateAcceptance</name>
    <solver>
        <localSearch>
            <localSearchType>LATE_ACCEPTANCE</localSearchType>
        </localSearch>
    </solver>
</solverBenchmark>
<solverBenchmark>
    <name>GreatDeluge</name>
    <solver>
        <localSearch>
            <localSearchType>GREAT_DELUGE</localSearchType>
        </localSearch>
    </solver>
</solverBenchmark>
<solverBenchmark>
    <name>Tabu_LA</name>
    <solver>
        <localSearch>
            <acceptor>
                <entityTabuSize>7</entityTabuSize>
                <lateAcceptanceSize>400</lateAcceptanceSize>
            </acceptor>
            <forager>
                <acceptedCountLimit>1000</acceptedCountLimit>
            </forager>
        </localSearch>
    </solver>
</solverBenchmark>
```

But now it seems that OptaPlanner executes three phases (construction + 2 x local search). I had expected the localSearch configuration from inheritedSolverBenchmark and plannerBenchmark to be merged. Is that not the case?

Answer (score 0):

No, I am afraid it's not.

When inherited, the SolverConfig's `phaseList` gets list-merged, not overwritten, nor list-element-merged:

- Nobody want's overwritten (as that would just ignore what's in the inherited config), so that's not it.
- list-merged: some cases want this. I 've used it a lot to define a CH in the inherited config and the LS variants in the single benchmarks.
- list-element-merged: what you're asking. Some cases want this.

We can't detect automatically if it's a case that needs list-merged or list-element-merged, so we had to make a choice and we went with list-merged.

Fix: Either declare it more verbosely or look at the Freemarker template support.

Comment: Thanks Geoffrey! Ideally, indeed you want both list-merge and element-merge. I also specified CH in the inherited config. For now, I went with the more verbose copy-paste of the neighborhood definition. Not a problem of course, since this config is not production code (in my case). I also tried the Freemarker support, which served me well to fine tune parameters.